# CSS rotation changes direction when transform is set during transition in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I found a very weird behaviour (it wasn't easy to find the exact circumstances under which it appears, but I am now at least able to reproduce it consistently) in Chrome.

If I have an element with a transform style attribute that contains either of translateX, Y or Z and a transition on the transform property, then when I apply 90 degrees of rotation to it, and before the transition finishes I set the rotation to 180 degrees, it suddenly switches directions.
It does the same with -90 followed by -180 as well.

You can find a minimal demonstration here: https://jsfiddle.net/gy313qon/5/
Or as one html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .translated {
      transform: translateX(0px);
    }

    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 200px;

      border: solid black 1px;

      transition: transform 2000ms;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="translated" id="box"></div>
  <script>
    const box = document.getElementById('box')

    setTimeout(() => { box.style.transform = 'rotate(90deg)' }, 0)
    setTimeout(() => { box.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)' }, 1000)
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you remove the translation or change it for example to a scale, it works as expected. Also, I have tried it in Microsoft Edge as well, and I see no problem there. Is this a known issue with Chrome? I found that it does the same in the Canary build.

---

**Edit**: There is some really messed up stuff going on. I just tested Joseph Marikle's comment and it seems to work in Chrome with (90 => -180) as well as (-90 => 180), but in Edge (-90 => 180) does what it really should (turns back), but (90 => -180) continues. O.o

---

**Edit 2**: It seems like putting an initial "rotate(0deg)" into the default style of the element prevents this glitchy behavior, but I would still like to see some kind of explanation or an acknowledgement as a bug.

Comment: not sure about the problem, seems fine to me: https://jsfiddle.net/gy313qon/4/

Comment: `90` followed by `-180` works though :P

Comment: @DanielH I messed up the link at first, please check the new one!

Comment: @JosephMarikle Wow, I didn't think about that one. :D I might implement handling it that way it in my app as an abstraction if no better solution is found. Thank you very much indeed!